# CSS property background-clip:text is not working for me in chrome or safari

Tags: css, html

I don't get why the background-clip property is not working in chrome and safari.

i try to put the prefix -webkit but it doesn't help.

The page is located here http://pierredebroux.be/charleroi/

the code is mainly:

```
 <div id="laphoto" class="image2">
   <div id="zz">
    <h1>OBSERVER CHARLEROI</h1>
  </div>


     .image2 {
     position: fixed;
        width:100%;
        height: 100%;
        background: url(img/a.jpg) 50% 50%;
        background-size: cover;
        background-clip:text;
        color:transparent;
        opacity: 0;
        filter:blur(2px)
    }

   h1 {
     font-size: 190px;
    line-height: 180px;
  }
```

Thanks,
Pierre

Comment: Hi, people could help you better if you posted your relevant code instead of linking directly to a web page.

Comment: `background-clip`works in most versions of all major browsers, It shouldn't need `-webkit` prefixes. https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-clip.asp

Comment: yeat it shouldn't be used  but it's not working on chrome.

Comment: For the code  it 's just the use of `background-clip : text` and `color:transparent`

Answer (score 2):

I guess the minute error in your code is `opacity:0;`.
It will set the background invisible. try removing it. Also `-webkit-` prefix is required for `background-clip:text;`. 
I have attached a [code pen](https://codepen.io/sidonkar/pen/XBMGEz) for reference.

Comment: In 2022 one still needs this in MS Edge. This surprised me!